# Artifactory - SSL & Crowd connection question

Tags: ssl, connection, artifactory, atlassian-crowd

I am trying to connect Artifactory on premise to our LDAP within the company.  In the LDAP setup screen, everything was entered, including the "Manager Password".  Once all entered, I click on 'Test Connection', and the connection was successful.  After I saved the changes, and come back to this page to try another 'Test Connection', Artifactory says the LDAP connection fails.

I tried same connection with Crowd, and same problem.  It looks like there's a problem with the stored password.  Please let me know if I miss any steps here.  Thanks.

Updated 2/28/18 - looks like with Chrome, once I entered the password, without saving anything and click test, all working.  But once the entries are entered are saved, the password content got modified (because of encryption?)  Then when I test again, the connection fails.  I don't face any issue using IE.

Comment: seems strange, the passwords are encrypted once we have entered the password for testing. what is the version of artifactory you are running ?

Comment: @yashbagarka It's version 6.7.3

Comment: couldn't find anything open in case of LDAP issue. Can you send the artifactory logs when the password is getting denied.